# Components of vector given two orthogonal vectors and an angle

Tags: geometry

This is probably quite easy but I wanted to find an elegant way of obtaining the components of a vector ($\overrightarrow{P}$) given a plane defined by two orthogonal vectors ($\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$) and the angle ($t$) of the new vector with respect to the first vector ($\overrightarrow{a}$).

[image]
(**NOTE**: dimension of vectors is greater than 2)

In other words, considering that I have:

$\overrightarrow{a}=(a_x,a_y,a_z)$

$\overrightarrow{b}=(b_x,b_y,b_z) \perp \overrightarrow{a}$

$t = \textrm{Angle}(\overrightarrow{a},\overrightarrow{P})$

$\overrightarrow{P}=(P_x,P_y,P_z) \in \textrm{Plane}(\overrightarrow{a},\overrightarrow{b})$

What is an elegant way of expressing $F$ such that:

$\overrightarrow{P} = F(\overrightarrow{a},\overrightarrow{b},t)$

Comment: Hint: How would you do this if $a$ and $b$ were the standard basis vectors?

Comment: Assuming that all your vectors have unit norm, this is fairly easy to do once you take @amd 's comment into account. Throwing in one more hint: this involves trigonometric functions.

Comment: I did a*cos(t) + b*sin(t). Is this correct?

Comment: If $\|a\|=\|b\|=\|P\|=1$, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [@John Wayland Bales](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/246513/john-wayland-bales)' suggestion, I'll post my comments as a proper answer.
Assuming unit norms for all three vectors, it is fairly easy to express $P$ as a combination of $a$ and $b$. Taking the potential non-unit norm into account we end up with:
$$
\frac P{\|P\|} = \cos t\frac a{\|a\|}+\sin t\frac b{\|b\|}
$$

Assuming we're working with vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, we then obtain the formulas:
\begin{align*}
\frac{P_x}{\|P\|} &= \cos t\frac{a_x}{\|a\|} +\sin t\frac{b_x}{\|b\|}\\
\frac{P_y}{\|P\|} &= \cos t\frac{a_y}{\|a\|} +\sin t\frac{b_y}{\|b\|}\\
\frac{P_z}{\|P\|} &= \cos t\frac{a_z}{\|a\|} +\sin t\frac{b_z}{\|b\|}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know the magnitude $\Vert P\Vert$.

Then you have

\begin{eqnarray}
\cos t&=&\frac{P\cdot a}{\Vert P\Vert\cdot\Vert a\Vert}\\
\sin t&=&\frac{P\cdot b}{\Vert P\Vert\cdot\Vert b\Vert}
\end{eqnarray}

Furthermore you know that

\begin{equation}
P\cdot a\times b=0
\end{equation}

where

\begin{eqnarray}
P_xa_x+P_ya_y+P_za_z&=&\Vert P\Vert\cdot\Vert a\Vert\cos t\\
P_xb_x+P_yb_y+P_zb_z&=&\Vert P\Vert\cdot\Vert b\Vert\sin t\\
P_x(a_yb_z-a_zb_y)+P_y(a_zb_x-a_xb_z)+P_z(a_xb_y-a_yb_x)&=&0
\end{eqnarray}

So

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_x&a_y&a_z\\
b_x&b_y&b_z\\
a_yb_z-a_zb_y&a_zb_x-a_xb_z&a_xb_y-a_yb_x
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
P_x\\P_y\\P_z\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\Vert P\Vert\cdot\Vert a\Vert\cos t\\
\Vert P\Vert\cdot\Vert b\Vert\sin t\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
So the solution of this equation will give the components of $P$.

By the way, the determinant of the matrix equals $\Vert a\times b\Vert^2$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit simpler to use $\frac P{\|P\|}=\cos t\frac a{\|a\|}+\sin t\frac b{\|b\|}$?

Comment: @N.Bach Yes. Which reinforces my contention that if there is a convoluted way to do something, I will find it. :) You should post that as an answer.